# How to Clear Model's Property Value Using Jquery and Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two cascading Dropdowns 
First dropdown has 2 values : (Negative and Positive)
So If I select Negative from first Dropdown, second dropdown should appear with 3 more values and if I select Positive, second dropdown should have 2 values.
This business logic is working fine.

But When I select Negative and a value from second dropdown and then I change my first dropdown's value so I want the Model property for second dropdown should get clear as it still contains previous selected value

For this I have a ajax call to controller which would handle everything

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetValue(id) {
    if ($("#firstDropdownID option:selected").index() == 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ResetDropdownValues", "ControllerName")',
            data: '{ id: ' + id + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                 alert("error : " + reponse);
              },
            error: function(reponse) {
                 alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }</script>
```

And this is the controller where I want to access current model to clear its property

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetDropdownValues(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            //Access Current Model state to clear value for a particular property
        }


        return null;
    }
```

And this is the code to change value of second dropdown returning JSonResult

```
if (!$("#firstDropdownID option:selected").index() == 0) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#secondDropdownID ").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetSecondDropdownValue", "ControllerName")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: '{ id: ' + id + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Type of Issue</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#secondDropdownID ").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function(reponse) {
                // alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
```

And the controller which is returning JsonResult

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSecondDropdownValue(int id)
    {
        List<ExperienceType> obj_ToIssue = new List<ExperienceType>();
        if (id == 1)
        {
            obj_ToIssue = GetValue().Where(m => m.Id != 0).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            obj_ToIssue = GetValue().ToList();
        }

        SelectList obj= new SelectList(obj, "Id", "Name");
        return Json(obj);
    }
```

Comment: This makes no sense. In the `.change()` event of the first dropdownlist, you call a method that returns a `JsonResult` of the values you want for the 2nd dropdownlist, and build the `<option>` elements - refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey thanks for the reply but I am doing this already to generate values but I need to clear the model somehow for some different scenario as my dropdown are optional in my case so I don't have validation applied on them so it can also have empty values in datatbase.

Comment: Why you are calling controller for cascading dropdownlist!!? Its can be be easily done by **Javascript/Jquery** by returning 'JsonResult' .

Comment: Can you please little bit more what different scenario you talking about?? And are you trying to say that your one of your dropdown (I guess 1st one) could be empty?

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad 
1st scenario:
If I select first value in first dd and select a value from second dd so,the property of second dropdown in model will contain the selected value of second dropdown.

2nd Scenario:
If after that I change the value of first dd and the second dd will now have different values according to the first dd(using JsonResult) now second dd will have 'select any value' as a text but now second dd in this case is optional so if I submit the form without selecting anything from the second dd  it will still send the value to db which was selected in first scenario.

Comment: You last comment makes no sense, and the 2nd dropdown will not _send the value to db which was selected in first scenario_ unless you code is wrong (and you have not shown it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Have a look on it now, I have updated it.

Comment: The first issue you have is that you give the label option a value - it should be `<option value="">Select Type of Issue</option>` (i.e. a `null` vaue) so that it posts back `null` (and I am assuming that the property you are binding to is nullable but you have not shown you model of the controller code)

Comment: In addition, you should return only the data you need i.e. `var obj = obj_ToIssue.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Name });` rather that a `SelectList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks alot for you help.
<option value="">Select Type of Issue</option>

Making this change worked for me, so having it set to zero was not allowing null it was always having a value no matter what.